# How to change a :lang selector style with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a very simple multilingual static website using only HTML5, CSS3 and vanilla (raw) JavaScript.

Suppose HTML looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WEBSITE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 lang="en">ENGLISH HEADER</h1>
      <h1 lang="fr">FRENCH HEADER</h1>
      ...
    </header>
    <main>
      <article lang="en"><p>...</p></article>
      <article lang="fr"><p>...</p></article>
      ...
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want english to be default language, so on my CSS I do:

```
header h1:not(:lang(en)), main article:not(:lang(en)) {
  display: none;
}
```

When a user changes their display language preference through a `<select>` I have a `onChange=""` event tag that executes a JS function. I don't have much experience with JS, and I'm wondering if there's a way to overwrite that style with a similar one for the user's desired language.

Please keep in mind that I'm purposefully avoiding any JS framework and jQuery for the sake of keeping this website as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another approach, similar to your initial CSS approach. First we add a global/body-level `lang` attribute with `en` as our value (as we want it the default).

We then can apply our CSS as:

```
body[lang="en"] [lang="fr"], // if <body lang=en>, hide all lang=fr
body[lang="fr"] [lang="en"]{ // if <body lang=fr>, hide all lang=en
    display: none;
}
```

The inverse (or, `:not`, as you were asking) would look like:

```
body[lang=en] [lang]:not([lang=en]),
body[lang=fr] [lang]:not([lang=fr]) {
    display: none;
}
```

Then in our select handler, we can just modify the body-level `lang` attribute. As simple as:

```
function langChange(el) {
  document.body.setAttribute('lang', el.value);
}
```

Here's a snippet you can test with:

```js
function langChange(el) {
  document.body.setAttribute('lang', el.value);
}
```

```css
body[lang="en"] [lang="fr"],
body[lang="fr"] [lang="en"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body lang="en">
  <header>
    <h1 lang="en">ENGLISH HEADER</h1>
    <h1 lang="fr">FRENCH HEADER</h1>
    ...
  </header>
  <main>
    <article lang="en">
      <p>English Paragraph</p>
    </article>
    <article lang="fr">
      <p>French Paragraph</p>
    </article>
    ...
  </main>
  <select onChange="langChange(this)">
    <option selected value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

(Here's an example of the `:not` usecase, as well as outputting the selectors with a CSS preprocessor: https://jsfiddle.net/o7vxskzL/)

Comment: This is really simple and it's mostly CSS! It's probably much more efficient than the way I've found. Thank you so much!

Comment: As a side note however, although this method is very good if it's just a two or three languages, it would be very painful to write the combination for n languages on the css code, wouldn't it? For such cases, when there's a arbitrary number of languages it would seem to me that using selectors would be the best method.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while. Regarding your comment, you're correct regarding n combinations. There's probably a way to optimize this (if you wanted to stick with mostly CSS) by leveraging a CSS preprocessor like LESS/SASS/etc. and building out the language selectors programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a way, I don't know whether this is the best way to do it, but it works.

Basically, what I've done is select all non `langX` elements with `document.querySelectorAll("tag:not(lang(langX))")` and made each of them invisible, after that I made all `langX` elements visible similarly.

It turns out it was quite simple.